# Image stretching when orientation changes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I had done an application in iOS for image editting.When we pick an image and if it will take in portrait ;then we change it's orientation to landscape image became  stretched.Ho we can fix this?

Comment: So you can't use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this issue by showing the image in single orientation.That means in which orientation we pick the image ;we showing the image only in that orientation only.I refer many application in App Store many of them following this idea.